# Global search - Implement search functionality with CodeIgniter and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, search

I have 5 tables i.e. Table 1, Table 2 and so on. Every table has two to three column names and thousands of values in it.

I am looking to implement search functionality in a website where the user will be putting a search term and my model should hit database(all the tables), search for a particular word and get all the results.

I tried searching all the tables one by one but that's not the best and optimized approach. CodeIgniter should have something for this kind of functionality.

What do you use for search function on your websites?

Comment: you can build your own algorithm

Comment: The simplest solution is to do it concurrently. ie you can spawn 3 threads which will search from all three tables and then combine the result.

Comment: so if one query takes 2 seconds you will get result in about 3-5 seconds which in sequential would take 6-8

Comment: How about Full-Text search? I don't think concurrent query will be the best way to handle global search.